# Этимология слова "коверкать"

Tags: этимология

Заинтересовала этимология слова "коверкать" (искажать). Даже не могу представить, от какого слова оно может быть образовано.
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Шанского: КОВЕРКАТЬ - исконное слово от несохранившегося веркать - бросать, валить, глухой вариант от вергать: свергать, низвергать, отвергать. КО - это приставка, она сходна по значению с приставкой СО

ИЗ ИНТЕРНЕТА
"Приставка ко- часто имеет то же значение, что и со-: совместность, совместимость. Прежде приставка ко- чаще использовалась в научных терминах: «кофермент», «кофактор» и др. 
Теперь стали появляться слова общего употребления. Весьма популярным стало слово «коспонсор» (дополнительный спонсор, соспонсор). Не так давно встретилось слово коавтор (то есть соавтор). Хотя некоторые из подобных неологизмов режут слух".

Приставка КО встречается в таких словах, как "закоулок, колупать, конура". Закоулок буквально — "то, что находится за тем, что примыкает к улице".Конура - это нечто похожее на нору. Получается, что приставка КО передает значение смежности и подобия (в этом она ОТЧАСТИ сходна с приставкой ПРИ: гора - пригорок).

В итоге: коверкать (портить, ломать, уродовать) имеет тот же РЕЗУЛЬТАТ, что " бросить, кинуть,свалить".